# Is it possible to find two following tags with Floki (Elixir html parser)?

Tags: html, css-selectors, elixir

I'm trying to parse a number of html documents with Elixir and [Floki](https://github.com/philss/floki/). I've got a lot of documents with the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
  ...
  <div>
    <label>Topic 1</label>
    <span>Data 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Topic 2</label>
    <span>Data 2</span>
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>

  <label>topic for table 1</label>
  <table>content of the table 1</table>

  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>

  <legend>
    <h2>topic for table 2</h2>
  </legend>
  <table>content of the table 2</table>

  <div>
    <label>topic for table 3</label>
    <table>content of the table 3</table>
  </div>

  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Everything was ok when I was working with `<div><label>...</label<span>...</span></div>` subtrees: I was able to use Floki to get `label n` and `data n` and correctly use it accordingly to `label`.

But I can't figure out how to get a **pair** of `label` + `table` or `legend` + `table` siblings. I can get tables by `Floki.find(body, "label + table")`, but I need to get a text from a previously (immediatly before table) described `label``legend` tag to understand what to do with a table on top of that label.

So I'd like to kindly ask for a help. Here is [a link](http://rosrid.ru/nioktr/A8X6CEKYD3IK68DX9B3YBHEV) to the live sample of such documents if one need it.